# Two dimensional scatter plot using latex

Tags: luatex, diagrams, asymptote, metapost

I have a two dimensional array of integers. I want to draw a scatter plot with the data like this:

```
for(i=0, i<length(row), i++)
for(j=0, j<length(column), j++)
if data[i][j] is positive put a red mark else put a green mark.
```

Could anybody give an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`Asymptote` version

```
// "2dscatter.asy"
// to get a standalone 2dscatter.pdf image, run
//    asy 2dscatter.asy
//
settings.outformat="pdf";
size(9cm);
srand(351767147);
int m=17, n=11;
real[][] data=new real[m][n];

// generate some random integer data table
for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) 
  for(int j=0; j<n; ++j) 
    data[i][j]=round((unitrand()*2-1)*m*n);

guide mark=scale(0.5)*unitcircle;

for(int i=0; i<m; ++i) for(int j=0; j<n; ++j){
  fill(shift(i,j)*mark,(data[i][j]>0)?red: green);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one idea -- but since you provide no data, I have just populated the data array with random numbers.  This is done with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`, so you should compile it with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
numeric n, data[][];
n = 8;
for i=1 upto n:
    for j=1 upto n:
        data[i][j] = normaldeviate;
    endfor
endfor

beginfig(1);
    for i=1 upto n:
        for j=1 upto n:
            drawdot (i,j) scaled 6 
                withpen pencircle scaled 4 
                withcolor if data[i][j] > 0: red else: green fi;
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```